# How can I break lines in a TikZ node used for \paragraph{…}

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

How to break the long title in the below code into lines? I have tried `\\`  and `\newline` without success.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{pgfornament,adjustbox}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}.\;}
%---------------------------------------------------
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} 
%---------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\fancydraw}{% Defining a command to shorten things
    \begin{adjustbox}{max height=0.5\baselineskip}% Rescaling to have height of 0.5\baselineskip
        \rotatebox{90}{% And rotating 90 degrees
            \pgfornament{26}% Ornament n° 26 (http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/véc-tơian/psvéc-tơian.pdf)
        }%
    \end{adjustbox}%
}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{-3.2pt}{8pt}{8pt}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\footnotesize\bfseries\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont}
{}
{0.2em}
{\centering% Centering the title
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {\fancydraw \hspace{1em} \theparagraph #1 \hspace{1em} \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\fancydraw}};
        \draw[line width=.6pt] ([yshift=16pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=16pt]todotted.south east); % 5 pt above
        \draw[line width=.6pt] ([yshift=-3pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-3pt]todotted.south east); % 5 pt below
        %       \draw ([yshift=-7pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-7pt]todotted.south east); % and 7 pt below
    }
}[]
\begin{document}
    \paragraph{This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can put \paragraph inside a minipage, \parbox or \vbox, but you need to specify the width.

Comment: @JohnKormylo IMHO this would not help. The problem here is not `\paragraph` but using a TikZ node. So putting `\paragraph` inside a `minipage` … would not help. Yes, you could put a `\parbox` inside the node, but better use TikZ features for multi-line nodes (see my answer). If you think, I'm wrong, please show an answer with `\paragraph` inside a `minipage` … and with line breaks.

Comment: See the chapter on nodes and multiline in the pgfmanual, which shows several approaches.

Comment: I would be very surprised if TikZ did not implement `[text width=...]` with some kind of `\vbox`, or `[align=...]` with a tabular.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are generating your `\paragraph` titles using TikZ. To automatically allow line breaks in a TikZ `\node`, you just have to set the allowed `text width`. For multi-line nodes, also using `todotted.south` as reference point for the line above is not suitable. Better use `todotted.north`. So you could, e.g., change

```
    \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {\fancydraw \hspace{1em} \theparagraph #1 \hspace{1em} \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\fancydraw}};
    \draw[line width=.6pt] ([yshift=16pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=16pt]todotted.south east); % 5 pt above
```

into

```
    \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,text width=\linewidth] (todotted) {\fancydraw \hspace{1em} \theparagraph #1 \hspace{1em} \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\fancydraw}};
    \draw[line width=.6pt] ([yshift=5pt]todotted.north west) -- ([yshift=5pt]todotted.north east); % 5 pt above
```

For more formatting options for the multi-line text of a node, see section “17.4 The Node Text”, i.e., “17.4.3
Text Parameters: Alignment and Width for Multi-Line Text” in the TikZ manual. For example, you could add `align=center` for horizontal centering of the title:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}
%\usepackage{extsizes}% DOES NOT MAKE SENSE WITH CLASS extbook
\usepackage{pgfornament,adjustbox}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}.\;}
%---------------------------------------------------
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} 
%---------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\fancydraw}{% Defining a command to shorten things
    \begin{adjustbox}{max height=0.5\baselineskip}% Rescaling to have height of 0.5\baselineskip
        \rotatebox{90}{% And rotating 90 degrees
            \pgfornament{26}% Ornament n° 26 (http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/véc-tơian/psvéc-tơian.pdf)
        }%
    \end{adjustbox}%
}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{-3.2pt}{8pt}{8pt}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\footnotesize\bfseries\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont}
{}
{0.2em}
{\centering% Centering the title
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,text width=\linewidth,align=center] (todotted) {\fancydraw \hspace{1em} \theparagraph #1 \hspace{1em} \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\fancydraw}};
        \draw[line width=.6pt] ([yshift=5pt]todotted.north west) -- ([yshift=5pt]todotted.north east); % 5 pt above
        \draw[line width=.6pt] ([yshift=-3pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-3pt]todotted.south east); % 5 pt below
        %       \draw ([yshift=-7pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-7pt]todotted.south east); % and 7 pt below
    }
}[]
\begin{document}
    \paragraph{This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title This is long title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't need automatic line breaks, but manually with `\\` only, you can also use `node halign header`. This would reduce the length of the lines to the natural maximum with of the lines. In the following example, I use a definition for centered title:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}
%\usepackage{extsizes}% DOES NOT MAKE SENSE WITH CLASS extbook
\usepackage{pgfornament,adjustbox}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}.\;}
%---------------------------------------------------
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} 
%---------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\fancydraw}{% Defining a command to shorten things
    \begin{adjustbox}{max height=0.5\baselineskip}% Rescaling to have height of 0.5\baselineskip
        \rotatebox{90}{% And rotating 90 degrees
            \pgfornament{26}% Ornament n° 26 (http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/véc-tơian/psvéc-tơian.pdf)
        }%
    \end{adjustbox}%
}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{-3.2pt}{8pt}{8pt}

\def\paragraphheader{\hfil##\hfil\cr}% Used in the TikZ node of following \titleformat
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\footnotesize\bfseries\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont}
{}
{0.2em}
{\centering% Centering the title
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,node halign header=\paragraphheader] (todotted) {\fancydraw \hspace{1em} \theparagraph #1 \hspace{1em} \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\fancydraw}};
        \draw[line width=.6pt] ([yshift=5pt]todotted.north west) -- ([yshift=5pt]todotted.north east); % 5 pt above
        \draw[line width=.6pt] ([yshift=-3pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-3pt]todotted.south east); % 5 pt below
        %       \draw ([yshift=-7pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-7pt]todotted.south east); % and 7 pt below
    }
}[]
\begin{document}
\paragraph{This is long title This is long title\\
  This is long title This is long title\\ This is long title This is long title\\ This is long title This is long title\\ This is long title This is long title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See the difference to the image of the first example.

Comment: cabohah, thanks a lot.